Maui - TabbedPage bind Tabs to ViewModel causes NavigationFailed error
I got this Problem and hopefully someone could help to solve it.
Sample Project download
**File: HomePage.xaml **
If I use this xaml without Viewmodel Binding it works normally:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.Views.HomePage"
             Title="HomePage"
             x:Name="mainTabPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <page:HomeContentPage Title="Home" />
    <page:SettingsContentPage Title="Settings" />

</TabbedPage>

But if I change it like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.Views.HomePage"
             Title="HomePage"
             x:Name="mainTabPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">

    <TabbedPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:HomePageViewModel/>
    </TabbedPage.BindingContext>

</TabbedPage>

HomePageViewModel:
public partial class HomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public HomePageViewModel()
    {
        SetMainTabsTest();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<Page> _tabCollection = [];

    [ObservableProperty]
    public Page _selectedTab = null;


    private void SetMainTabsTest()
    {
        TabCollection.Clear();

        TabCollection.Add(
            new HomeContentPage
            {
                Title = "Home"
            });

        TabCollection.Add(
            new SettingsContentPage
            {
                Title = "Settings"
            });

        SelectedTab = TabCollection[0];
    }
}

HomeContentPage:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.Views.HomeContentPage"
             Title="HomeContentPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Dummy text for Home Page"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

SettingsContentPage:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPageTest.Mvvm.Views.SettingsContentPage"
             Title="SettingsContentPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Dummy text for Settings Page"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

I got the error Message: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.NavigationFailed was unhandled.
Debug, Exception - Inner Exception and ask Google but no result

your 2nd example has a VM but no other content

You add new bindings in second example. Please share what those properties are

Post is updated.

TabbedPage is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be thrown if you attempt to use TabbedPage in a Shell app. Which I can see your app is.
Another issue might be that you have your viewmodel as transient, this may add new instances of the page which might not be ideal in some cases.
